# Google App Engine: Kind Error

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

Following is my program

```
import os    
import jinja2    
import re    
from string import letters    
import webapp2    
from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')
jinja_env= jinja2.Environment(loader= jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),autoescape= True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self,*a,**kw):
        self.response.write(*a,**kw)

    def render_str(self,template, **params):
        t= jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self,template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template,**kw))

def blog_key(name = "default"):
    return db.Key.from_path('blogs',name)

class Post(db.Model):
    title= db.StringProperty(required= True)
    content= db.TextProperty(required= True)
    created= db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add= True)
    edited= db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now= True)

    def render(self):
        self._render_text= self.content.replace('\n', '<br>')
        return render_str("blogs.html", p= self)

class BlogFront(Handler):
    def get(self):
        posts= db.GqlQuery("select * from posts order by desc limit 10")
        self.render("front.html", posts=posts )

#for a link to the new posts created
class PostPage(Handler):
    def get(self, post_id):
        key= db.Key.from_path("Post", int(post_id), parent= blog_key())
        post=db.get(key)

        if not post:
            self.error(404)
            return

        self.render("permalink.html", post=post)

#for new blog entries
class NewPost(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('newpost.html')

    def post(self):
        title= self.request.get("title")
        content= self.request.get("content")

        if title and content:
            p= Post(parent= blog_key(), title=title, content=content)
            p.put()

            self.redirect('/blogs/%s' % str(p.key().id()))
        else:
            error= "Please write both title and content!!"
            self.render("newpost.html",title=title, content=content, error=error)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
      ('/blog/newpost', NewPost), 
      ('/blogs/?',BlogFront),
      ('/blogs/([0-9]+)',PostPage),    #anything in the bracket will be passed as the parameter

], debug=True)
```

But when I'm trying to implement this program, I'm getting the following error:

> File "C:\Users\tan31102\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platfo
>   rm\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db__init__.py", line 299, in
>   class_for
>   _kind
>       raise KindError('No implementation for kind \'%s\'' % kind) KindError: No implementation for kind 'posts'

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the model definition in the Py file that uses it. This causes the `KindError`.

`from posts import posts`

or something similar.

It sounds like you are trying to load a `posts` entity from a session without importing the `posts` model first.

To ensure that `posts` is available when the session middleware runs, you must import the `posts` model in your script.

Comment: Glad to help @Taylor. Keep coding and stay happy! Cheers. Hope your project is a success.

Answer (score 1):

Your gql uses post in plural form - "posts"

`select * from posts order by desc limit 1`

while the db.Model class you have declared uses posts in singular form (Post)

```
class Post(db.Model):
```

You need to stick with either form. Also you should consider using ndb.Model instead of db.Model [as stated in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/modelclass)

Comment: Thanks @Arne. That Indeed was a stupid mistake. But that does not solve the problem. I'm still getting error while running the program